# How can I get a full stack trace in my custom plugin log?

Tags: plugin-development, logging, error-handling

I'm using `MyPlugin::log` to separate the errors for my plugin. However, I'm only able to log a simple message using this technique.

Is it possible to have that output the **full stack trace**?

Here's what I'm getting (note the general format)...

```
2015/06/09 20:41:42 [error] [plugin] My example error message.
in /craft/app/etc/plugins/BasePlugin.php (65)
in /craft/plugins/businesslogic/services/BusinessLogicService.php (194)
in /craft/plugins/businesslogic/controllers/BusinessLogic_ActivitiesController.php (47)
```

But here's what I **want** (again, note the general format)...

```
2015/06/09 20:39:25 [error] [exception.CException] exception 'CException' with message 'Craft\BusinessLogic_ActivitiesController and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "handleError".' in /craft/app/framework/base/CComponent.php:266
Stack trace:
#0 /craft/plugins/businesslogic/controllers/BusinessLogic_ActivitiesController.php(47): CComponent->__call('handleError', Array)
#1 /craft/plugins/businesslogic/controllers/BusinessLogic_ActivitiesController.php(47): Craft\BusinessLogic_ActivitiesController->handleError()
#2 /craft/app/framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php(49): Craft\BusinessLogic_ActivitiesController->actionUpdate()
```

How do I get the #0, #1, #2, etc. to show up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default a full stack trace will only be assembled and logged if an exception is thrown (which is what you're looking at in your 2nd example) mainly for performance reasons - cycling through the backtrace and assembling all of that info is a relatively expensive operation.

Standard calls to `MyPlugin::log` or `Craft::log` will get a partial backtrace added to each message.  The depth of that is controlled by the `YII_TRACE_LEVEL` PHP constant, which Craft sets to 3 by default.

If you want to have them log deeper into the trace, set that to a higher number in your public index.php file, just be aware of the performance implications.

There is some discussions of that constant here in the Yii docs: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging#logging-context-information

Comment: Very interesting! So if I were to make that change in my index.php, it would affect **all** plugins? Is it possible to trigger the logging _as an exception_ (instead of as "plugin")?

Comment: Yeah, it would affect all plugins (and Craft!). Can't think of a way around it without getting super hacky.

Comment: Last question... In the Yii docs you link to, I see a reference to `Yii::trace`. Is that something that Craft passes through (and/or would it be useful in this case)?

Comment: Also, this may be more configurable in Yii 2/Craft 3 - still need to look into it.

Comment: `Yii::trace` only gets logged when devMode is enabled.  It's where 95% of the extra devMode logging info comes from.